# Pandas DataFrame - 'cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [float64]' when using ols/linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, linear-regression

I have a DataFrame as follows:

|  | Ticker | Date | Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ADBE | 2016-02-16 | 78.88 |
| 1 | ADBE | 2016-02-17 | 81.85 |
| 2 | ADBE | 2016-02-18 | 80.53 |
| 3 | ADBE | 2016-02-19 | 80.87 |
| 4 | ADBE | 2016-02-22 | 83.80 |
| 5 | ADBE | 2016-02-23 | 83.07 |

...and so on. The `Date` column is the issue. I'm trying to get the linear regression of the `Date` column with the `Close` column:

```
ols1 = pd.ols(y=ADBE['Close'], x=ADBE['Date'], intercept=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [float64]
```

I've tried multiple ways of getting rid of this error, for examples:

```
dates_input = ADBE['Date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]')

dates_input = ADBE['Date'].values.astype('float')
```

The second `dates_input` attempt returns the type as `pandas.core.series.Series` but I still get an error message.

Does anyone know how to get the `Date` column to work and get rid of this TypeError?

Answer (score 17):

You need:

```
ADBE['Date'] = ADBE['Date'].values.astype(float)
```

and then:

```
ols1 = pd.ols(y=ADBE['Close'], x=ADBE['Date'], intercept=True)
```

Comment: I made a mistake; for others who might make the same mistake; be careful not to use `Series.astype(float)` (as in; `pd.Series(ADBE['Date'].values).astype(float)`; notice @jezrael's answer uses `ndarray.astype(float)` (directly on the `.values.astype(float)`)

Comment: I was getting the error
 TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32] 

when trying to run the line 
df_['Date']=(df['Date'].astype(int)// 10**9).astype('U10')

Changing above line to
df['Date']=(df['Date'].values.astype(int)// 10**9).astype('U10')

solved by issue.