# Python - FamaMacBeth, cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [float64]

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-series, regression

When trying to run a `FamaMacBeth` regression on my dataset, I get the `TypeError`:

```
cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [float64],
```

My date column is of type `numpy.ndarray`

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11022):

> The problem is that we don't support the datetime64[s] type on pandas objects, even though it's a valid type for NumPy arrays.

A possible workaround is converting directly to float, as in the comment on this question:

[Pandas DataFrame - 'cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [float64]' when using ols/linear regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453744/pandas-dataframe-cannot-astype-a-datetimelike-from-datetime64ns-to-float)